# c++ pimpl and abstract class together

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pimpl-idiom

Please take a look at the following code (a code is worth a thousand words):

shape.hpp

```
class Shape {
public:
    double area() const;
private:
    class ShapeImpl;
    ShapeImpl* pimpl;
};
```

---

shape.cc

```
// ABS
class Shape::ShapeImpl {
public:
    double area() const = 0;
};


class Circle : public Shape::ShapeImpl { // error: Shape::ShapeImpl is private
public:
    double area() const {return pi*r*r;}
};


double Shape::area() const {
    return pimpl->area();
}
```

---

I know where the error comes from, but I'm more concerned with good practices. My questions:

1. In the case of the above code, is mixing Pimpl with ABC a bad idea?
2. if not, what is the best way to avoid the error (keeping encapsulation, etc.)?
3. if yes, what I have to do to obtain polymorphism while hiding implementation from the user (in my `Shape` scenario)?

Obs: Assume that performance is not a problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Its a fine idea. For reference, here is the letter/envelope idiom, due to Coplien.
   [ You can use an `enum` instead; obviously need to handle errors etc.
   The parallel being that the base type is public and the implementation hidden. See below.
2. I'd just make the initial `ShapeImpl` declaration public; what problems does that cause?

See:  [example with a Shape](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/cpp/envelope/ex2/)

Comment: Very enlightening example, thanks. I'd have made `ShapeImpl` public too, but because I'm new to Pimpl idiom, I was not sure about to changing things that I had seen in examples out there. Maybe I'm worrying too much about best practices ...